# View not being drawn on top of GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, glsurfaceview

I'm trying to make a pause menu come up when the user presses the menu button (pauses the game). The game does successfully pause, but nothing draws...maybe it's drawing underneath my GLSurfaceView? Here's my code.

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {

private GLSurfaceView mGLSurfaceView;
private static final String TAG = "Game";
private MainGamePanel mGame;

private View mPauseMessage = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("GameSettings", MODE_PRIVATE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mGLSurfaceView = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.glsurfaceview);
    mPauseMessage = findViewById(R.id.pausedMessage);

    mGLSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(false); // 16 bit, no z-buffer

    mGame = new MainGamePanel();
    mGame.setSurfaceView(mGLSurfaceView);

    ....
    mGLSurfaceView.setRenderer(mGame.getRenderer());

}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    boolean result = true;
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        if (mGame.isPaused()) {
            this.resume();
            if (mPauseMessage != null) {
                mPauseMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } else {
            this.pause();
            if (mPauseMessage != null) {
                mPauseMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

protected void pause() {
    super.onPause();

    mGame.onPause();
    mGLSurfaceView.onPause();
}


protected void resume() {
    super.onResume();

    mGame.onResume();
    mGLSurfaceView.onResume();
}
```

And from my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<android.opengl.GLSurfaceView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            android:id="@+id/glsurfaceview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pauseMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone">
    <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/pausedMessage"
    android:src="@drawable/pause"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you have a line somewhere saying:

```
mGLSurfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

Which overrides OpenGL to draw above anything, even if you have other views on top of it in your RelativeLayout. Try commenting this out if you have one.

Otherwise you can try this: (thank you user2610335)

```
mGLSurfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem. But in my case pauseMenu was INVISIBLE, but not GONE. When I changed it to GONE, all worked fine. But that happend only on some devices. Maybe try View.bringToFront()